# SystemMediaTransportControls Not Working

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm having issues with the new SystemMediaTransportControls that replace MediaControl.

Currently, I have my app set up with:-

```
        systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        systemControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        systemControls.IsStopEnabled = true;
        systemControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
        systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;
```

And

```
        async void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.Button);
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            switch (args.Button)
            {
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                    if (mediaElement1.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
                    {
                        restartSource();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completeClosure();
                    }
                    break;
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Stop:
                    completeClosure();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

And:

```
        private async void completeClosure()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaElement1.Stop();
            mediaElement1.Source = null;
            timer.Stop();
        });
    }

    private async void restartSource()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(holdThisSource, UriKind.Absolute);
            mediaElement1.Play();
            timer.Start();
        });
    }
```

When a user presses the Pause Button, args.Button shows up as "Play", hence the need for the checking for MediaElement's state. However, when I attempt to resume to media, it successfully resumes in restartSource() and updates the app accordingly but the icon on the Volume Control does not change from the Play sign, although hardware buttons still work.

Along with this, pressing the hardware Stop button NEVER works, and fails to even show up in Debug.WriteLine.

This is an online streaming app where the source does not allow resuming and thus I have to close the stream this way.

I'd love some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not update the `systemControls.PlaybackStatus`, the control button on transport control will not auto change to correct status.

You should always update the `systemControls.PlaybackStatus` property when the playback state has changed.

May this could solve your problems.